# Cannot convert value of type to expected PFQueryArrayResultsBlock?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

I'm getting the following error in my Parse query: `Cannot convert value of type '([PFObject]?,_) throws -> ()' to expected argument type 'PFQueryArrayResultsBlock?'`

I'm not sure why this is throwing an error. I let the autocomplete create the block for me. Here's the relevant code:

```
gameQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results: [PFObject]?, NSError) in
                for result in results {
                    //code
                }
            })
```

I know using `[AnyObject]` used to throw this error in the older SDK's but this should work with `[PFObject]`. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the error parameter name. Try this.

```
gameQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
                for result in results {
                    //code
                }
})
```

Comment: `gameQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in` still throws `Cannot convert value of type '([PFObject]?, NSError?) throws -> ()' to expected argument type 'PFQueryArrayREsultsBlock?'`. Not sure why this is